# Prove and draw this metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$$d(x,y) =    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      |x_1-y_1| & \text{iff} &
      x_2=y_2 \\
      |x_1|+|x_2-y_2|+|y_1| & \text{iff} & x_2 \neq y_2 \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

$a)$ Prove this is a metric

$b)$ Draw the unit sphere centered at $(0,0)$ with respect to this metric

$c)$ Draw the unit sphere centered at $(1,1)$ with respect to this metric

### My attempt

$a)$ Two cases:

case $1$: $x_2=y_2$

$i)$ Show $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x=y=0$

$$d(x,y)= |x_1 - y_1| = |0-0| = 0 \checkmark$$

$ii)$ Show $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for all $x,y$

$$d(x,y)=|x_1 - y_1|= |-y_1+x_1|=|(-1)(y_1-x_1)|=|-1||y_1-x_1|=d(y,x) \checkmark $$

$iii)$ Show $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

$$d(x,z)= |x_1 - z_1|=|x_1 - y_1 + y_1 -z_1| \leq |x_1 - y_1|+|y_1-z_1|=d(x,y)+d(y,z) \checkmark $$

case $2:x_2 \neq y_2$

$i)$

$$d(x,y)=|x_1|+|x_2-y_2|+|y_1|=0 \\\text{iff}: x=y=0$$

$ii)$

$$d(x,y)= |x_1|+|x_2-y_2|+|y_1|=|y_1|+|-y_2+x_2|+|x_1|=|y_1|+|-1||y_1-x_2|+|x_1|=d(y,x)$$

$iii)$

$$d(x,z)=|x_1|+|x_2-z_2|+|z_1|=...$$
Not sure how to do this one.....................

$b)$ This is a unit sphere so $d(x,y)=1$. Let $x=(0,0)$ if $y_2=0$ then $$d(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|=|0-y_1|=|y_1|=1$$
Therefore this is only possible for points $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$

If $y_2 \neq 0$ then:
$$d(x,y)=|x_1|+|x_2-y_2|+|y_1|=|0|+|0-y_2|+|y_1|=|-y_2|+|y_1|=|y_2|+|y_1|=1$$
$$|y_2|+|y_1|=1$$

I can choose points such as $(0,1),(0,-1),(.5,.5)$ and the graph looks like a diamond

$c)$ Let $x=(1,1)$. If $x_2=y_2=1$ Then: 
$$|1-y_1|=1$$
$$|-y_1|=|y_1|=1$$

So possible points are $(1,1),(-1,1)$

If $y_2 \neq 1$:

$$|1|+|1-y_2|+|y_1|=1 $$
$$|1-y_2|+|y_1|=0$$

Impossible to add two positive values and get zero. So there are no other possible points??

Can anybody help me with proving $iii)$ and help me with possible things that I messed up on?

Comment: This is called the River Metric on $\mathbb R^2.$ Lines of the form $\mathbb R\times \{y\}$ are separated from each other by mountains. The river is $\{0\}\times \mathbb R.$ So to get from $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(y_1,y_2)$ when $x_2\ne y_2$  you have to travel on the line $\mathbb R\times \{x_1\}$ to the point $(0,x_1)$ on the  river,  and travel on the river to  ($0,x_2),$ and travel on $ \mathbb R\times \{x_2\}$ to $(x_2,y_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Property 1: The distance should be zero if $ x = y $ regardless if $ x = 0 $ or not. Also, notice that if $ x = y $ then necessarily $ x_2 = y_2 $, so the "Case 2" you gave is moot.

Property 3: You need several cases. One is if the three points are in a horizontal line, which you proved already. Then you need a case where two points are in a horizontal line, and finally you need the case where no points share $ y $ coordinate.

Part b): You should look at several cases, cases where $ y = 0 $ and where $ y \neq 0 $.

Comment: I am done now. Would you be able to help me with the parts that I messed up on?